# C socket : connect error - invalid argument

Tags: c, sockets, tcp

I made a simple Process-based parallel socket program.

My client code reaches the connect part and throws an Invalid argument error, and my server doesn't ouput anything. just cursor...

I split the terminal in two to run the code.

I run the code with:

```
gcc -o p-server p-server.c -Wall
./p-server
```

```
gcc -o p-client p-client.c -Wall
```

The output is

> 

> [C] Connecting...
> [C] Can't connect to a Server: Invalid argument

**p-server.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
//#include <sys/wait.h>

#define BUFFSIZE 4096
#define SERVERPORT 7799

int main(void){
    int i, j, s_sock, c_sock;
    struct sockaddr_in server_addr, client_addr;
    socklen_t c_addr_size;
    char buf[BUFFSIZE] = {0};
    char hello[] = "Hello~ I am Server!\n";
    
    //int option = 1;
    //setsockopt(s_sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &option, sizeof(option));
    
    bzero(&server_addr, sizeof(server_addr));
    server_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server_addr.sin_port = htons(SERVERPORT);
    server_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("10.0.0.131");

    s_sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

  
    if (bind(s_sock, (struct sockaddr *) &server_addr, sizeof(server_addr)) == -1) {
        perror("[S] Can't bind a socket");
        exit(1);
    }

    if(listen(s_sock, 5)) {
        perror("[S] Can't listen");
        exit(1);
    }
    
    c_addr_size = sizeof(client_addr);

    
    for ( i=0; i<3; i++) {
        if ((c_sock = accept(s_sock, (struct sockaddr *) &client_addr, sizeof(client_addr))) == -1 ){
            perror("[S] Can't accept a connection");
            exit(1);
        }

        printf("[S] Connected: client IP addr=%s port=%d\n", inet_ntoa(client_addr.sin_addr), ntohs(client_addr.sin_port));

        
        //fork
        switch(fork()){
            case 0:
                close(s_sock);
                //1. say hello to client
                if(send(c_sock, hello, sizeof(hello)+1, 0) == -1) {
                    perror("[S] Can't send message");
                    exit(1);
                }

                printf("[S] I said Hello to Client!\n");

                //2. recv msg from client
                if(recv(c_sock, buf, BUFFSIZE, 0) == -1) {
                    perror("[S] Can't receive message");
                    exit(1);
                }

                printf("[S] Client says: %s\n", buf);
                exit(0);
        } 
        
        close(c_sock);
    }

    
    /*
    for(j=0; j<3; j++){
        wait(&status);
        printf("Patren waits %d\n"), wstatus;
    }*/
}
```

**p-client.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

#define BUFFSIZE 4096
#define SERVERPORT 7799

int main(void){
    int c_sock;
    struct sockaddr_in server_addr;
    socklen_t c_addr_size;
    char buf[BUFFSIZE] = {0};
    char hello[] = "Hi~I am Client!\n";

    if((c_sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == -1) {
        perror("socket");
        exit(1);
    }
    
    bzero(&server_addr, sizeof(server_addr));
    server_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server_addr.sin_port = htons(SERVERPORT);
    server_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("10.0.0.131");

    printf("[C] Connecting...\n");

    if (connect(c_sock, (struct sockaddr *) &server_addr, sizeof(server_addr) == -1)) {
        perror("[C] Can't connect to a Server");
        exit(1);
    }

    printf("[C] connected!\n");

    //1. recv msg from server (maybe it's "hello")
    if (recv(c_sock, buf, BUFFSIZE, 0) == -1) {
        perror("[C] Can't receive message");
        exit(1);
    }

    printf("[C] Server says: %s\n", buf);

    //2. say hi to server
    if(send(c_sock, hello, sizeof(hello)+1, 0) == -1) {
        perror("[C] Can't send message");
        exit(1);
    }

    printf("[C] I said Hi to Server!!\n");

    printf("[C] I am going to sleep...\n");
    sleep(10);

    close(c_sock);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hmm... where is `SERVERPORT` defined in client?

Comment: Your third argument to `accept` is wrong. It should be a `socklen_t*` not a `size_t`, and your compiler should have definitely either warned or outright error tripped on that mistake.

Comment: @SergeBallesta I declared `SERVERPORT ` as a global variable.

Comment: Not really, `SERVERPORT` is not a variable but just a macro.

Comment: `sizeof(hello)+1` This will access the array beyond it's limits. `sizeof` already includes the terminating 0 byte.

Comment: @WhozCraig Thanks. I modified the server code. `if ((c_sock = accept(s_sock, (struct sockaddr *) &client_addr, &c_addr_size)) == -1 ){ `   But the modified code has a same error.

Comment: @Gerhardh Thanks. But that is the send part, my code hasn't reached that yet... still connect before send

Comment: @Aine That isn't the only error. Your address setup isn't correct either. Honestly, you should just setup both addrs with `getaddrinfo` and `AI_PASSIVE` to populate the local addr, restricting the hints as warranted. It really does fill in the blanks for you.

Comment: I know, but it is still wrong and might bite you as soon as you manage to connect.

Comment: @Gerhardh Okay. Thank you for your help. I'll keep that in mind.

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in the brackets of your connect call

```
 if (connect(c_sock, (struct sockaddr *) &server_addr, sizeof(server_addr) == -1)) {
    perror("[C] Can't connect to a Server");
    exit(1);
}
```

Should be

```
if (connect(c_sock, (struct sockaddr *) &server_addr, sizeof(server_addr)) == -1) {
    perror("[C] Can't connect to a Server");
    exit(1);
}
```